# Tensorflow GPU on windows (too slow)

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I've installed Tensorflow on windows7 machine. Tensoflow does recognize the GPU. here is the output of the program(Don't have any print call in it):

```
    2017-05-11 16:28:03.039954: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-11 16:28:03.039954: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-11 16:28:03.039954: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-11 16:28:03.040954: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-11 16:28:03.040954: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-11 16:28:03.041954: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-11 16:28:03.353972: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:887] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 980 Ti
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.076
pciBusID 0000:83:00.0
Total memory: 6.00GiB
Free memory: 5.81GiB
2017-05-11 16:28:03.354972: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:908] DMA: 0 
2017-05-11 16:28:03.354972: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:918] 0:   Y 
2017-05-11 16:28:03.354972: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 980 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:83:00.0)
```

From what I understand, Tensorflow finds GPU and run the the whole program on it. the problem is that it's too slow comparing to my laptop. On the TF homepage, there is the following example: I've run it on

My laptop: Intel Core i7-CPU 2.59 GHz 8GB RAM 
and on  the workstation that has `Intel Xeon CPU E5-2670 0 2.6GHz CPU` and an `NVIDIA GeForve GTX 980 Ti GPU`

```
import tensorflow as tf 
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):# '/cpu:0'
    # Creates a graph.
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print(sess.run(c))
```

The results look as followed : 
My laptop:

```
MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
b: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
a: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
[[ 22.  28.]
 [ 49.  64.]]
2017-05-12 10:54:26.235444: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:841] MatMul: (MatMul)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
2017-05-12 10:54:26.235675: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:841] b: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
2017-05-12 10:54:26.235886: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:841] a: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
[Finished in 1.952s]
```

Workstation CPU:

```
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 980 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:83:00.0
MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
b: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
a: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
[[ 22.  28.]
 [ 49.  64.]]
[Finished in 2.924s]
```

Workstation GPU:

```
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 980 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:83:00.0
MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
b: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
a: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
[[ 22.  28.]
 [ 49.  64.]]
[Finished in 3.045s]
```

So my question is what I'm missing here and how can I solve this issue ?

Comment: @Shadow I'm update the question. I just wanted to point out, that since it and Xeon unit it can't be slower than my core i7 !

Comment: @Shadow  I "guess" single precision is the default one in TF

Comment: @Shadow can't answer  your question, I guess it's a TF bug ( found similar problem) I'm trying now to reconfigure the whole mess :/

Comment: You're wondering why a little 2x3 matrix mutliplication is not faster on the GPU?

Comment: Not only the small matrix but I got a bigger Network with 6 layers  and the laptop was faster !

Comment: How are you timing the runs? I don't know where the "Finished" output comes from. Likely you are mostly timing the Tensorflow startup time, and that takes longer on GPU. You really should use a benchmark with a nontrivial amount of computation if your goal is to measure throughput. Hope that helps!